# I can not trigger the alert when the form is empty after developing a clean code in pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript

The small code in pure HTML, without forgetting to set the method for `get`:

```html
        <form action="#" method="get">
          <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Nome"><br>
          <input id="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail"><br>
          <textarea id="message" name="name"  rows="8" placeholder="Dê-nos um elogio, uma reclamação ou um elogio"></textarea>
          <input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="send"><br>
        </form>
```

I refactored and made a clean code of the dirty multiple `if-else` statements, simplifying. After it, I can not trigger the alert.

The code `let send = document.getElementById("send");` checks the code `<input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="send"><br>`.

Before, in a dirty code, I had many `document.getElementById("email").value == ""` and simplified to:

```js
const fields = new Set([
  'name',
  'email',
  'message',
]);
```

I simplified three `'if-else` statements along with these `if-else` statements of identifiers. Firstly, it will check if the fields are empty, go to verify the length, `1` indicates only an empty field and `> 1` indicates more empty fields. Else they will check the fields are full and submit.

```js
function alert() 
{
  let required = fields.value == "";

  if (required.length == 1)
  {
    alert("The field is required!");
    required = []
  }

  else if (required.length > 1)
  {    alert("The fields are required!");
      required = []
  }

  else
  {
    document.getElementById("send").submit();
    alert("Thank you! The message was sent successfully")
  }
}
```

Finally, the code `send.addEventListener("click", alert)` indicates to click the function when sending, and `addEventListener` will trigger the alert.

Complete code in JavaScript:

```js
let send = document.getElementById("send");
const fields = new Set([
  'name',
  'email',
  'message',
]);

function alert() 
{
  let required = fields.value == "";

  if (required.length == 1)
  {
    alert("The field is required!");
    required = []
  }

  else if (required.length > 1)
  {    alert("The fields are required!");
      required = []
  }

  else
  {
    document.getElementById("send").submit();
    alert("Agradecemos, mensagem enviada com sucesso!")
  }
}

send.addEventListener("click", alert)
```

Comment: That won't work. The Set object does not provide a way to check the `.value` properties of multiple elements. Have you checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: Yes, and no errors. Empty result.

Comment: Also calling a function "alert" is probably a bad idea.

Comment: Because of accessibility matter?

Comment: Because browsers have a global `alert()` function already.

Comment: Let me say this again: what you're trying to do with that Set object will not work; the Set API has nothing at all to do with the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest that you create an event listener for `invalid` on the form. This will be called when one of the required fields empty/invalid (see the `required` attribute on all the fields). I made a custom alert that shows.

```js
var alert = document.getElementById('alert');

alert.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.nodeName == 'BUTTON')
    alert.classList.remove('show');
});

document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  console.log('The form will submit');
});

document.forms.form01.addEventListener('invalid', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert.classList.add('show');
}, true);
```

```css
#alert {
  display: none;
}

#alert.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form name="form01" action="#" method="get">
  <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Nome" required><br>
  <input id="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required><br>
  <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="8" placeholder="Dê-nos um elogio, uma reclamação ou um elogio" required></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="send"><br>
</form>
<div id="alert">The fields are required! <button>OK</button></div>
```

This is overruling the default behavior in the browser. In any case I think the `required` attribute is the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You may like to do something like this with your function:

```
 function showAlerts(){
    var allInputs = document.querySelectorAll('#name, #email, #message');
    if(null != allInputs){
     for(var i in allInputs){
        if(!isNaN(i)){
          // here you can check for values, emptiness etc
          if(allInputs[i].value.trim() === ''){
             // this field is empty
             alert('This field is required!');
          }
          ...
       }
     }
    }
  }
```

Comment: That `isNaN()` test will never find a `NaN`, because `.querySelectorAll()` will always return a list of zero or more element nodes.

Comment: like others have pointed out, you have already overwritten the alert global function provided by JavaScript.

Comment: @Pointy, by experience !isNaN() ensures that you are dealing with only numeric indexes.  It is just logical way of saying I want to work with only numeric indexes.

Comment: Well it won't hurt anything.